# ¿hola soy nuevo mi pregunta es como puedo quitar el erro que me marca mi programa?

Tags: c#

Apenas estoy aprendiendo a ocupar los archivos y a sobreescribirlos mi problema es que me marca el programa lo siguiente

[image: En esta imagen muesta el error que es un System.Indez.OutRangeException]

El codigo es el siguiente

```
int i, j;
                string[] lineas = new string[100];
                string linea;
                int contador = 0;
                string nombreArchivoleer = "Diauno.txt";
                try
                {
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(nombreArchivoleer);
                    //leo y verifico que no sea null (archivo vacío)

                    while ((linea = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        lineas[contador] = linea;
                        Console.WriteLine(linea);
                        contador++;
                    }
                    sr.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error al leer el archivo: " + e.Message);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
                for (j = 0; j < contador; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Contenido de la Línea {0}: {1}", j + 1, lineas[j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Inicia proceso de separación de datos...");
                string[] idSala = new string[contador];
                string[] Sala = new string[contador];
                string[] dia = new string[contador];
                string[] hora = new string[contador];
                string[] titulo = new string[contador];
                string[] ponente = new string[contador];
                for (i = 0; i < contador; i++)
                {
                    string[] Diauno = lineas[i].Split('|');
                    for (j = 0; j <= 10; j++)
                    {
                        if (j == 0)
                            idSala[i] = Diauno[j];
                        else if (j == 1)
                            Sala[i] = Diauno[j];
                        else if (j == 2)
                            dia[i] = Diauno[j];
                        else if (j == 3)
                            hora[i] = Diauno[j];
                        else if (j == 4)
                            titulo[i] = Diauno[j];
                        else if (j == 5)
                            ponente[i] = Diauno[j];
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Linea {0} de datos procesada: idSala[{1}]: {2}, sala[{1}]: {3}, dia[{1}]: {4}, hora[{1}]: {5} titulo[{1}]: {6} ponente[{1}]: {7}",
                       i + 1, i, idSala[i], Sala[i], dia[i], hora[i], titulo[i], ponente[i]);
                }
```

Lo que hace mi codigo es pedirle al usuario que ingrese un horario del dia que es el 7 de diciembre del 2021 y pedirle que sobreescriba el archivo pidiendole que ingrese un nuevo tema de la ponecia y el nombre de la ponencia

[image: La forma en como se construye el programa]

Aqui esta la parte del progrma en la que se ingresan los datos del usuario

```
Console.WriteLine("¿Qué horario deseas reservar?: " +
                    "\n1) 9 a 11 am" +
                    "\n2) 11 a 13:00 am" +
                    "\n3) 13 a 2 pm " +
                    "\n4) 2:10 a 3:30 pm " +
                    "\n5) 3:40 a 5 pm" +
                    "\n6) 5 a 7pm");
                horario = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (horario)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("El horario ya esta lleno");
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese otra horario");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("El horario ya esta lleno");
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese otra horario");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        string newTitulo, newPonente;
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el titulo de la ponencia: ");
                        newTitulo = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre del ponente: ");
                        newPonente = Console.ReadLine();
                        titulo[2] = newTitulo;
                        ponente[2] = newPonente;
                        for (i = 0; i < titulo.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("idSala: {0} sala: {1} dia: {2} hora: {3} titulo: {4} ponente: {5}", idSala[i], Sala[i], dia[i], hora[i], titulo[i], ponente[i]);
                        }
                        string[] lineasAguardar = new string[titulo.Length];
                        for (i = 0; i < titulo.Length; i++)
                        {
                            lineasAguardar[i] = idSala[i] + "," + Sala[i] + "," + dia[i] + "," + hora[i] + "," + titulo[i] + "," + ponente[i];
                        }
                        File.WriteAllLines("Diauno.txt", lineasAguardar);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el titulo de la ponencia: ");
                        newTitulo = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre del ponente: ");
                        newPonente = Console.ReadLine();
                        titulo[3] = newTitulo;
                        ponente[3] = newPonente;
                        for (i = 0; i < titulo.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("idSala: {0} sala: {1} dia: {2} hora: {3} titulo: {4} ponente: {5}", idSala[i], Sala[i], dia[i], hora[i], titulo[i], ponente[i]);
                        }
                        string[] lineasAguarda = new string[titulo.Length];
                        for (i = 0; i < titulo.Length; i++)
                        {
                            lineasAguarda[i] = idSala[i] + "," + Sala[i] + "," + dia[i] + "," + hora[i] + "," + titulo[i] + "," + ponente[i];
                        }
                        File.WriteAllLines("Diauno.txt", lineasAguarda);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el titulo de la ponencia: ");
                        newTitulo = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre del ponente: ");
                        newPonente = Console.ReadLine();
                        titulo[4] = newTitulo;
                        ponente[4] = newPonente;
                        for (i = 0; i < titulo.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("idSala: {0} sala: {1} dia: {2} hora: {3} titulo: {4} ponente: {5}", idSala[i], Sala[i], dia[i], hora[i], titulo[i], ponente[i]);
                        }
                        string[] lineasAguardara = new string[titulo.Length];
                        for (i = 0; i < titulo.Length; i++)
                        {
                            lineasAguardara[i] = idSala[i] + "," + Sala[i] + "," + dia[i] + "," + hora[i] + "," + titulo[i] + "," + ponente[i];
                        }
                        File.WriteAllLines("Diauno.txt", lineasAguardara);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el titulo de la ponencia: ");
                        newTitulo = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre del ponente: ");
                        newPonente = Console.ReadLine();
                        titulo[4] = newTitulo;
                        ponente[4] = newPonente;
                        for (i = 0; i < titulo.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("idSala: {0} sala: {1} dia: {2} hora: {3} titulo: {4} ponente: {5}", idSala[i], Sala[i], dia[i], hora[i], titulo[i], ponente[i]);
                        }
                        string[] lineasAguardaras = new string[titulo.Length];
                        for (i = 0; i < titulo.Length; i++)
                        {
                            lineasAguardaras[i] = idSala[i] + "," + Sala[i] + "," + dia[i] + "," + hora[i] + "," + titulo[i] + "," + ponente[i];
                        }
                        File.WriteAllLines("Diauno.txt", lineasAguardaras);
                        break;
                }
                break;
```

Lo que hace el usuario en esta parte es ingresar un horario luego le pedira que ingrese el nuevo tema de la ponencia y al final el nombre del ponente al finalizar lo va a sobreescribir en el programa y se saldra del programa una vez que se halla salido del programa volvera el usuario a entrar al programa ingresara un nuevo horario y tendra que ingresar una nuevo horario e ingresara el titulo de la ponencia y el nombre del ponente en mi caso solo lo hace una vez al querer ingresar mas de 1 vez los datos me marca este error espero haberme explicado bien y espero me puedan resolver mi duda soy nuevo en esto y apenas es la primera vez que veo archivos en c#

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. 1. No olvides que los signos de puntuación _existen_ :) 2. Evita lo más posible las imágenes, ya que no todos pueden visualizarlas. 3. El mensaje es bastante claro: ¿depuraste tu código? ¿Buscaste el significado del error? (De hecho, en ese mismo mensaje se explica su significado).

Comment: tu problema no tiene nada que ver con archivos. Te esta diciendo que vos queres ver o editar la posicion 10 de tu array y solo tiene 9 posiciones. Por eso te lanza una excepcion del tipo IndexOutofRangeException. A modo de ejemplo te puse la cantidad que tiene tu array.

Comment: Tu problema seguramente es porque tu archivo tiene mas de 100 lineas y estas declarando arrays de 100 posiciones.

Comment: que pasa si cambias esto: `string[] lineas = new string[100];` por esto: `string[] lineas = new string[1000];`